# Finding the right adapter to connect a hose and a faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, adapter

I am trying to connect this hose (thread size 2.0):

[image]

To [this faucet](https://www.pfisterfaucets.com/kitchen/product/portland-lg34-4p-1-handle-kitchen-faucet?modelNumber=LG34-4PS0) (thread size 1.0):

[image]

The caliper reads 2.5 metric millimeters for the female screw of the hose, and the male faucet screw is 19mm. I live in the USA and none of the adapters I find online make any sense in their imperial measurements.
Please help! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried physically going into a hardware store to look for the adapters?  IME, sinks often use some fairly weird threads, and because of that, every hardware store I've been to (CA,US) has a device right near the sink aerators which has bolts and nuts with all the common sink threads, and you can try screwing your devices into them to identify your thread types, and then that will lead you to the right adapter.

Comment: I agree! But I can't think of how I would bring my faucet into a hardware store - I don't know how to take it apart! I added a link to the model of the faucet in the question.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you buy a dozen different connectors for the faucet end, take them all home and see which one fits. You then return 11 of them. I've never had a problem doing that with my local big-box store, and if you go to a smaller hardware store & explain the problem, they'll probably tell you to do exactly that, and the guy will certainly remember you when you come back in an hour.

Comment: I actually just went to the hardware store and they were out of a lot of stuff - not even a single female adapter... told me to go to a plumbing store lol... oh well, there’s a decent answer now. Thanks for the help too

Comment: Every time I try any DIY stuff, I get so disappointed in humanity. Why can't the world just use metric. And why do humans sometimes lie about sizes? Two by fours aren't actually 2x4? Pipe *actual* diameters aren't the sizes we're supposed to buy? "Nominal vs actual"? WTF.  At this point I'm surprised we don't sometimes say "buy size 'penguin', unless it's a Wednesday, then buy size 'yellow'." If AI kills us or enslaves us, it's because THIS is how stupid humans are. As much as I love StackExchange, I should be able to know what size I need without coming here.

Answer (score 2):

You will need 2 adapters because nobody makes a single fitting that adapts from the 3/4" x 27 tubular spout thread directly to garden hose thread.

This was a common problem decades ago when portable dishwashers that hook to faucet spouts were more common.

First, adapt the tubular spout to one of the larger common aerator threads, then adapt that to hose thread, like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is super helpful thanks. Can you add the link to the page were I can buy the adapters? I think I already have the one on the very top of your image

Comment: The image on the top of my answer is from a plumbing distributor I deal with that does not sell retail The image on the bottom is from a link **you** posted in a comment: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H26LKK2

Comment: Any good plumbing shop in the US should have the stuff (probably NOT at a "big-box" store. My distributor is here: https://www.lasco.net/aeratorsadapters-adapters-c-360_367/

Answer (score 0):

Hose requires a "hose" male as on  hose bibb; it is close to 1/2 pipe -but not close enough. Hardware store will have hose adapters with a pipe thread ( male or female ) on the other end. Your chrome plated pipe looks like a "fine" thread ( not a pipe thread) from what I see of it. That implies is is part of a fixture.

Comment: I added a link to the model of the faucet in the question. Your answer puts me in the right direction, but I am still at loss to find the exact part that I need...

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you want will be found at a well-stocked hardware store in the plumbing area as a "portable dishwasher" hookup kit - often with a quick-connect fitting on each half, and frequently with an extra quick-connect half to remount the aerator, or with a different aerator built into it.

The faucet-end is normally one of a few specialized "aerator" threads (the part you most likely took off to find those threads) and the hose looks like a standard garden hose thread. Many kits include parts that will connect to several different aerator threadings (it's also worth checking if you have internal as well as external threads there - some faucets do, some don't, gives you more options if you do.)

Comment: I have an adapter that I use for the faucet (to use a filter) called "Faucet Aerator Adapter Full Flow FPT 3/4"-27 x MPT 55/64"-27 Chrome" but I'm not sure which part of this adapter's name corresponds to the faucet's screw. Maybe 3/4"-27? Assuming FPT means "female"?

Comment: 3/4 inch is pretty much exactly 19mm, and 55/64 inch is larger, so that's likely the one. Your adapter's Female Pipe Threads thread onto the faucet's Male Pipe Threads, which also supports that as being "the one"

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. So is what I'm looking for a FPT 3/4" x MPT 1"? What does the "-27" in the adapter name mean?

Comment: **NOT STANDARD PIPE THREADS.** The -27 is threads per inch, and is much finer than "standard" 3/4 inch pipe threads, which are 14 threads per inch. And the other end is GHT - Garden Hose Threads, not any pipe thread at all, if that's a normal hose. If it's not a normal hose, we'd need to see more detailed pictures of it to speculate, but it looks like a normal hose where I'd expect GHT.

Comment: As an aside, "standard pipe threads" are also nowhere near the "nominal diameter" since they are based on a relatively thick pipe with a HOLE that diameter in it, so they are much larger.

Comment: The threading on the hose screw is 2.0 and on the faucet it is 1.0 according to the thread counter tool I have (added this info to the question...)

Comment: ...measuring inch threads with metric tools you had better learn to count fractions to a fine degree, or better yet, get different, non-metric tools for the purpose. 25.4 is close to 27, but not 27. 12.7 is close to 11.5, but not 11.5 (which happens to be the TPI of standard garden hose threads.)

Comment: Ah, yes, a large part of my problem is not understanding imperial measurements and living in the USA. Although that's why I'm asking for help online  Your last comment lost me, wouldn't we convert the thread measurements (2.0 and 1.0) to imperial units? What are 12.7 and 11.5 measurements for?

Comment: You need 3/4 x 27 aerator thread x garden hose thread adapter

Comment: @JimmyFix-it thanks - yours is one of the most helpful comments yet. Would [something like this](https://www.amazon.com/Faucet-Adapter-Swivel-Aerator-Connect/dp/B07H26LKK2) work? I've googled your answer, but find the wrong ones (male instead of female etc)

Comment: Nope, that won't work by itself, see my answer below.